# Group by portion of field

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, split

I have a field in a PostgreSQL table, **name**, with this format:

```
JOHN^DOE
BILLY^SMITH
FIRL^GREGOIRE
NOEL^JOHN
```

and so on. The format is `LASTNAME^FIRSTNAME`. The table has `ID, name, birthdate and sex` fields.
How can I do a SQL statement with `GROUP BY` FIRSTNAME only ? I have tried several things, and I guess `regexp_match` could be the way, but I don't know how to write a correct regular expression for this task. Can you help me ?

Comment: Store first and last name in separate columns. (Or, at least create a view that returns separate columns.)

Comment: I cannot do that. This format I didn't designed myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `split_part()`:

```
group by split_part(mycol, '^', 1)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=792e78d94f866728fb157cc8a7e32c0f)**:

```
mycol         | split_part
:------------ | :---------
JOHN^DOE      | JOHN      
BILLY^SMITH   | BILLY     
FIRL^GREGOIRE | FIRL      
NOEL^JOHN     | NOEL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). Note that '^' needs to be escaped, since in many regexp dialects it means the beginning of the line or or the string. Extending your example with one more name, and using `group by` on the **first field**:

```
select
    count(*)
    , regexp_replace(tmp_col, '\^.*', '')
from
    (values
        ('JOHN^DOE')
        , ('BILLY^SMITH')
        , ('FIRL^GREGOIRE')
        , ('NOEL^JOHN')
        , ('JOHN^SMITH')
        )
    as tmp_table(tmp_col)
group by regexp_replace(tmp_col, '\^.*', '')
    ;
```

Prints:

```
 count | regexp_replace 
-------+----------------
     1 | BILLY
     2 | JOHN
     1 | NOEL
     1 | FIRL
(4 rows)
```

To `group by` on the **second field**, use a similar regex:

```
select
    count(*)
    , regexp_replace(tmp_col, '.*\^', '')
from
    (values
        ('JOHN^DOE')
        , ('BILLY^SMITH')
        , ('FIRL^GREGOIRE')
        , ('NOEL^JOHN')
        , ('JOHN^SMITH')
        )
    as tmp_table(tmp_col)
group by regexp_replace(tmp_col, '.*\^', '')
    ;
```

Prints:

```
 count | regexp_replace 
-------+----------------
     1 | JOHN
     1 | GREGOIRE
     1 | DOE
     2 | SMITH
(4 rows)
```